# How to echo server time in an array in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used below code,

```
<?php
 $this->settings['copyright'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Copyright' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'Please enter the copyright text you wish to appear in the footer left.' ),
        'std'     => '©2012-'<?php echo date("Y"); ?> 'here i write some more', //here i am trying to echo it, but i get the error below
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'general'
    );
?>
```

I got an error like as below,

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

`'©2012-'<?php echo date("Y"); ?> 'here i write some more',`

should be

`'©2012-'.date("Y").'here i write some more',`

```
        <?php
         $this->settings['copyright'] = array(
                'title'   => __( 'Copyright' ),
                'desc'    => __( 'Please enter the copyright text you wish to appear in the footer left.' ),
                'std'     => '©2012-'.date("Y").'here i write some more', //here i am trying to echo it, but i get the error below
                'type'    => 'text',
                'section' => 'general'
            );
        ?>
```

Comment: Working great thanks, will mark it as the correct answer in 12 min. Thanks again.